# How does this JS code look like in if...else format?

Tags: javascript

How would the following be written in an `if/else` format?

```
hours == 0 ? 12 : (hours > 12) ? hours - 12 : hours
```

Comment: Why the down-vote?  The OP may not be a native English speaker.

Comment: this isn't really a statement, either it's an assignment or the return value of a function..

Answer (score 1):

```
if (hours == 0) {
  return 12;
} else if (hours > 12) {
  return hours - 12;
} else {
  return hours;
}
```

Ideally, you should also use '===' operator instead of '=='.

Comment: "return".. might as well be assignment x) Question incomplete

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the appropriate way to the finale else inside of the firs else statement.

```
if(hours == 0) { 
   return 12
 } else {
   if(hours > 12){
     return hours - 12
   } else {
    return hours
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use brackets... look at the following sample

```
console.log(((hours==0)*12)+((hours>12)*-12)+hours));
```

Comment: nice solution, i often use the same, i think that´s the fastest way. I vote up.